# ssh connection hangs after < 1s

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a weird ssh issue that I haven't encountered previously.

Remote connections to a machine (theseus) hang after < 1s.

- Connecting from theseus to theseus (`ssh user@localhost` or `ssh user@ip`) is fine.
- Connecting from theseus => other machine is fine.
- theseus => other machine => theseus connects but hangs after <1s.
- session negotiation looks ok in /var/log/auth.log (sshd says "session opened for user", systemd-logind says "new session # of user", there doesn't seem to be an error after that)
- from othermachine `ssh user@theseus 'while date +%s.%N; do sleep 0.1 || break; done'` shows ~0.75s worth of output
- the process continues running on theseus after this time, but I get no output, I *can* `ctrl + c` the process

I reinstalled ssh-server and client on theseus and the only edit I've made to sshd_config is `UseDns no`.